# Standard input to C++20 range adaptors w/o temporary variables

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++20

I can read `int`s from standard input, transforming them into `odd` or `even`, writing the results to standard output:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::ranges::copy(
    std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
    std::istream_iterator<int>(),
    std::back_inserter(v)
    );
std::ranges::copy(
    v | std::views::transform([](int a_int){return a_int%2 ? "odd":"even";}),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " ")
    );
```

which can be done w/o temporary variables:

```
std::transform(
    std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
    std::istream_iterator<int>(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "),
        [](int a_int){return a_int%2 ? "odd":"even";});
```

How do I use C++20 Range adaptors to do this w/o the temps?

Something more like:

```
std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin)
    | std::transform([](int a_int){return a_int%2 ? "odd":"even";})
    | std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " ");
```

Comment: There's an [`istream_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges#:~:text=basic_istream_view,istream_view), apparently.

Comment: @HTNW unfortunately it is red, not documented yet, on cppreference.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always turn an iterator based algorithm into a view based one with [`std::ranges::subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange):

```cpp
std::ranges::copy(
    std::ranges::subrange(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>())
    | std::views::transform([](int a_int){return a_int%2 ? "odd":"even";}),
    std::ostream_iterator<const char*>(std::cout, " ")
);
```

Though in this case there is a specialised `std::ranges::istream_view<T>`, which is essentially equivalent to the subrange:

```cpp
std::ranges::copy(
    std::ranges::istream_view<int>(std::cin)
    | std::views::transform([](int a_int){return a_int%2 ? "odd":"even";}),
    std::ostream_iterator<const char*>(std::cout, " ")
);
```